# Failure of functional test for 'create' using should_redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing, shoulda, factory-bot

I have a problem trying to use 'shoulda' with 'factory_girl' for creating a functional test for 'create' in a Rails application.  I created a  simple project, scaffolded user, added  'shoulda'  (current gem version on my system  2.11.3 ) and 'factory_girl' in test_helper.rb. Creating the user manually works fine.  Following are the steps to reproduce the failure :

1. rails project
2. scaffold user name:string
3. add in test_helper.rb :

   > ```
   >   require 'shoulda'  
   >   require 'factory_girl'
   > ```
4. rake db:migrate
5. write the following functional test for user (override users_controller_test.rb ) :

   ```
   class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    Factory.define(:user) do |u|
     u.name 'joe'
    end
    context "should create user" do
     context "with valid data" do
      setup do
        User.any_instance.expects(:save).returns(true).once
        User.any_instance.stubs(:id).returns(1001)
        post :create, :user => {}
      end
      should_assign_to :user, :class => User
      should_set_the_flash_to "User was successfully created."
      should_redirect_to("user page"){user_path(1001)}
     end
    end
   end
   ```
6. Running the test with "rake test:functionals" shows failure :

> Expected response to be a redirect to `<http://test.host/users/1001>` but was
>   a redirect to `<http://test.host/users>`.

I played also with "should  redirect_to", because I saw "should_redirect_to" is deprecated, 
but with no luck.  Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you in advance,

Marian Vasile Caraiman.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the correct redirection occurs when manually creating a user?

Comment: It is working fine when manually creating a user. Also, the other 2 asserts are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stubbing `User#id`, stub `User.create` and use particular user mock object.

```
setup do
  mock_user = Factory.stub(:user, :id => 1001)
  User.expects(:create).returns(mock_user)
  mock_user.expects(:save).returns(true)
  post :create, :user => {}
end
```